# How to handle exception while clicking link using textview in android

Tags: java, android, hyperlink, textview

I am working on an android project in which i have to add links i am following the given below example.. But when i am clicking on the link neither it is highlighting nor i am able to access the link. Clicking on the link is causing an exception which says

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

I want to open the link in the browser when  i am clicking on the link.How to do it efficiently?. I am expecting an answer soon !Thank you

*NB: i am using a dynamic textview in my actual project*

```
 public class StackOverflowActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView link = new TextView(getApplicationContext);
    String linkText = "Visit the <a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>StackOverflow</a> web page.";
    link.setText(Html.fromHtml(linkText));
    link.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `android:autoLink="web"` in your `TextView` xml. And if it does not work, try `android:linksClickable="true"`

Based on your error, if using dynamic `TextView` make sure you refer your view with `this` object as

```
TextView yourView = new TextView(this);
```

`this` refers to your `Activity` context where I think you might have made a little mistake.

You should not use `getApplicationContext` for creating a view with `Activity` context.

Comment: In my actual project i am using a dynamic text view. How to do it using java code?

Comment: Then post your actual code. You should do like `TextView yourDynamicView = new TextView(this);` `this` is important as it refers to your `Activity` Context.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to inflate the layout that contains your TextView before you can use it, like so:

```
getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
```